# Grabbing biggest number in String form regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get the biggest number (1,000,000) from this string in javascript

```
var teststr = "jUDGES/COACHES: \

jAcKsoN PALMeR 1 ATIF NAZlR l jAMES BLAHA l DAVEWl1gGENT \
PITCH PROTOTYPE PRESENT \
YOUR PRODUCT \
ul;&quot;&quot; \
1 \
bra GWDEAWAYS \
GRAND PéizE \
1,000,000 DOG COIN \
€ Prize PUbNUlS Prize \
750,000 DOGECOIN 750,000 DOGECOIN \
AFTER PARTY WITH SPECIAL GUEST Dj \
jACKSON PALnkjnjnkjMER \
JULY 26TH 3PM -]ULY 27TH 11PM";


function parseReg(string) {
  //var re = "(\d+)((.?)(\d+))+([\.\d\d]?)";
  return /(\d+)((.?)(\d+))+([\.\d\d]?)/g.exec(string);
}

console.log(parseReg(teststr));
```

But right now the output I get from developer tools is:

```
["1,000,000", "1", ",000", ",", "000", "", index: 187, input: "jUDGES/COACHES:     jAcKsoN PALMeR 1 ATIF NAZlR l … PALnkjnjnkjMER     JULY 26TH 3PM -]ULY 27TH 11PM"]
```

I'm pretty new to javascript so I'm not quite sure how to do this. I believe I got the regular expression correct but I'm not sure why the letters are being grabbed

Comment: You can't do it just with regex. Once you have a proper pattern to grab all numbers you will have to create some algorithm to check which is the biggest.

Comment: "Biggest" as in highest or as in longest?

Comment: @JorgeCampos how come it is grabbing letters? I'm not sure where `index:` is included?

Comment: i thought \d only grabs digits

Comment: i think it's not the job for regex.

Comment: Jorge has the right of it. It's a two step problem. Parse out the numbers, then take the maximum.

Comment: this `\d+(?:,\d+)+` would parse out the numbers which are separated by comma.

Comment: Your parseReg function returns a object with several properties, such as index and input. Just use your matched groups, and ignore the other properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
function parseReg(str) {
    var re = /(?:[\d,]*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g;
    var m;
    var greatestNumber = NaN;
    while(m = re.exec(str)) {
        var parsedNumber = parseFloat(m[0].replace(/,/g, ""));
        if (!isNaN(parsedNumber))
            greatestNumber = isNaN(greatestNumber) ? parsedNumber : Math.max(greatestNumber, parsedNumber);
    }
    return greatestNumber;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R2pmZ/

This function will return the greatest number in your string, or `NaN` if no number is found.